# Is it possible to change the labels of icons in the GNOME app grid?

Tags: gnome, icons

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with GNOME 42.2, and I want to change icon labels in the app grid (the "Show Applications" button that is 9 small squares arranged in a grid).  I've tried using *menulibre* and *alacarte*, but the changed labels aren't reflected in the grid.

Is there a way to do this?

Update:
Menulibre shows the labels, and the ~/.local/share/applications folder has the updated *.desktop files.

[MenuLibre and the new .desktop files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no0QQ.png)

But the app grid is being stubborn.

[The App Grid that isn't showing the new labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ8Sq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In order for this to work, you need to *save* your changes. e.g. in MenuLibre, confirm the name by clicking the checkmark, *then hit the save button*:

[image]

Comment: That change is reflected in menulibre, but not in the GNOME app grid.  Do I need to reboot?

Comment: Clicking the "Save" button saves out a modified .desktop file, which should be seen in your application overview within seconds. I specially installed MenuLibre to check and test this for you.